# How to set ui-router param from data i get from the API

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a bunch of states wherein i have the :activeproject param before the remaining url eg:

```
 .state('currenturls', {
            url: '/:activeproject/current/urls',
 .state('currentfiles', {
            url: '/:activeproject/current/files'
```

through JWT auth, I can find out the user that is logged in and their active project name via the API so for example, lets say the value of the current users 'activeproject' is 'my-project', then what i want to do is append the activeproject name in all such urls, so in the currenturls state, the url is:
/my-project/current/urls
and in currentfiles, its
/my-project/current/files

how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

How about defining a function, which builds your string depending on the value of a certain variable:

```
window.projectName = "myProject";

function getState() {
    return "/" + window.projectName + "/current/urls"
}

.state('currenturls', {
    url: getState()
})
```

Then change `window.projectName` whenever you change the user context.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply; tried what you suggested but every state including currenturls seems to break with the following error in the console: http://i.imgur.com/MdaqWsG.png

Comment: Can you please post more code? Maybe use a JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks :-) here's a sample state: http://pastebin.com/7J1jqm3v - instead of doing it in the url itself, i thought it might be interesting to try doing it in resolve but for whatever reason, with the code that i've pasted, it does not seem to be working - would be great to get your thoughts on this new approach and the code 

P.S: it works fine when i pass the param value in $state.go or ui-sref but again not what i want to be doing :-)